# How to pass a unix date to moment js without having this error : "Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format."

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I read through all other similar questions and still can't find a solution to my issue.

I have an app in node.js that use moment.js.

(1st) The app `get` a UNIX date through an HTTP request to an API and (2nd) then pass it to moment.js like this

```
const contractEndDate = 1619740800000;
const readablecontractEndDate = moment(`${contractEndDate}`, "x").format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
const preparationPeriod = 90;
const taskDate = moment.utc(contractEndDate).subtract(preparationPeriod, 'days').valueOf();
const readableTaskDate = moment(taskDate).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
console.log(`contract end date is ${readablecontractEndDate} and task date is ${taskDate} or ${readableTaskDate}`)

/*Output: Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

 Arguments: 
2020-01-15T22:17:30.182889+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _useUTC: true, _l: undefined, _i: 1619740800000, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

*/
```

It works fine in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/lumi/pen/bxrjZw?editors=0011

But I don't get why it doesn't work when I run my app.

Comment: https://github.com/adopted-ember-addons/ember-pikaday/issues/156 // Does this solves your issue?

Comment: What version of moment you use?

Comment: I don't really get why but the day after the same code was working without any error... @AntonRusak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get why but the day after the same code was working without any error

```
const contractEndDate = 1619740800000;
const readablecontractEndDate = moment(`${contractEndDate}`, "x").format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
const preparationPeriod = 90;
const taskDate = moment.utc(contractEndDate).subtract(preparationPeriod, 'days').valueOf();
const readableTaskDate = moment(taskDate).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
console.log(`contract end date is ${readablecontractEndDate} and task date is ${taskDate} or ${readableTaskDate}`)
```